# CQ5 hybris integration

Tags: aem, sap-commerce-cloud

I am working on integrating Hybris with CQ ecommerce. I am following the documentation on - http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/ecommerce/eCommerce-framework.html

However one of the steps is to import the catalog from Hybris into CQ through the Hybris catalog importer - 
localhost:4502/etc/importers/hybris.html

When I open this link: I have an error "Resource dumped by HtmlRendererServlet"
if someone has already try that; thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you get any more information from your console? For instance, a stack trace.

Comment: nothing written in the console;

Comment: Actually, I have just the developper version of "crx" but I  didn't install cq5 and I don't know if crx is sufficient to do the integration between hybris and crx;??

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same error -- resolved when I noticed an inactive bundle in CQ's OSGI console: CommerceService interface.   See /system/console/bundles and ensure all non-fragments are active.